# taffydb using OR and AND in single query

Tags: javascript, taffydb

My TAFFYDB() has rows that look like this (for example):

```
[
{"rowID":0,"objID":"hema","objVal":1,"objType":"n"},
{"rowID":0,"objID":"osmo","objVal":1,"objType":"n"},
{"rowID":0,"objID":"mot","objVal":1,"objType":"n"},
{"rowID":0,"objID":"morph","objVal":1,"objType":"n"},
{"rowID":0,"objID":"ph","objVal":0,"objType":"n"},
{"rowID":0,"objID":"conc","objVal":0,"objType":"n"}
]
```

I want to query out on 2 conditions:

1. morph or mot must have the value of 1
2. ph and osmo must have the value of 0

for matching rowID's

I'm trying like this:

```
var ret=anaDataDB(
            [ 
                [ [{"objID":"morph","objID":"mot"}] ,{ "objVal":1} ] ,
                [ [{"objID":"osmo"} ] ,{ "objVal":0 } ],
                [ [{"objID":"ph"} ] ,{ "objVal":0 } ]
            ]       
            ).get();
```

but I'm getting too many values. For instance, values where ph=1. 
I think the way I have it is using OR and I want AND between the 3 comparisons.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TaffyDB's query system is a bit awkward until you get used to it.

The simple trick to it is this: The elements within an array are considered part of an `OR` condition. Matching is attempted on objects. If the object in the parameter fits the record you are looking for, it will be returned.

```
var ans = anaDataDB(
    [
        {objID:["morph", "mot"], objVal:1},
        {objID:["osmo", "ph"], objVal:0}
    ]
    ).get();
```

This returns:

```
[ { rowID: 0,
    objID: 'mot',
    objVal: 1,
    objType: 'n',
    ___id: 'T000002R000004',
    ___s: true },
  { rowID: 0,
    objID: 'morph',
    objVal: 1,
    objType: 'n',
    ___id: 'T000002R000005',
    ___s: true },
  { rowID: 0,
    objID: 'ph',
    objVal: 0,
    objType: 'n',
    ___id: 'T000002R000006',
    ___s: true } ]
```

You're saying:

"I want the record if it has an objID of "morph" `OR` "mot" where the objVal is 1, `OR` if the record has an objID of "osmo" `OR` "ph" where the objVal is 0."

Objects are for matching, arrays make an `OR`.

Comment: wow... so long looking for how to use OR. Thank you. This should be in the 1st level document